# Paypal Integration Issue with Chrome browser (No ack for post Message getdelegateoverride)

Tags: .net, paypal, blazor, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I was trying to integrate paypal javascript sdk with blazor WASM. It is working fine with firefox but getting this error while runnning on Chrome (Paypal popup window to sign-in)

Network:

[Network info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hpim.png)

Console error:

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZamU.png)

To integrate PayPal with blazor WASM by using PayPal buttons. Paypal login window keeps on loading in chrome and then close unexpectedly with this error (in chrome only)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)